# function scope in javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.plugin = {

    loadedcss   : [],

    add: function(params) { 
        $.each(params["css"], function(key,value) { 
            // this.loadedcss error undefined
            this.loadedcss.push(value);
        });
    },

    end: function(){
        //console.log(this.loadedcss);
    }
};
```

as you can see im **trying to push my new css params** to `loadedcss` variable. and it says *error undefined* this.loadedcss maybe there is something that i miss

```
$.plugin.add({
    css: ['framework.css','csstest.css']
}); 

$.plugin.add({
    css: ['framework.css','csstest.css']
}); 

    $.plugin.end();
```

how can we push my `params['css']` to `this.loadedcss` ?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/fxsUf/

Comment: sorry updated i miss the real code.

Comment: BTW, you have `css` and `js` mixed up in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try,

```
$.plugin = (function(){
var methods = {
   loadedcss   : [],

    add: function(params) { 
       // IF IN ARRAY NOT LOADED THEN PUSH CSS
      if ($.inArray(params['css'],this.loadedcss) == -1) {
         // error undefined this.loadedcss
         methods.loadedcss.push(params['css']);
       };
     },
     ...
   };

return methods;
})();
```

It will allow you to use internal vars as well as a side affect.

Alternatively,

```
add: function(params) { 
    var me = this;
    $.each(params["js"], function(key,value) { 
        // this.loadedcss error undefined
        me.loadedcss.push(value);
    });
}
```

Will also work

Comment: return methods at the end.. i didn`t find this any where in the books, any good link andrew ? thanks

Comment: @Andrew I think you have your syntax wrong - the method return pattern is normally used either with `new` (which isn't used by jQuery plugins) or as the return value of an _immediately invoked function expression_.  You'd need to wrap it so: `$.plugin = (function() { ... } )()`

Comment: @user397916 Not really, I learnt it from reading the jQuery source. It's just really nice because it lets your plugin have private variables.

Comment: @user397916 An example can be found in the jQuery [Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) Guide

Answer (score 1):

Alias the `this` parameter to something else (`self` in the example below) and then use that alias instead inside your callback function.

```
add: function(params) { 
    var self = this;
    $.each(params["css"], function(key,value) { 
        self.loadedcss.push(value);
    });
},
```

You can't use `this` inside the callback because `$.each()` will have set it to the current array element's value.

Answer (score 0):

`$.plugin` is just a an object. It should be a function in order to create a new instance of it then you can use `this` in its methods. You can try this now

```
$.plugin = {

    loadedcss   : [],

    add: function(params) { 
        $.each(params["js"], function(key,value) { 
          // this.loadedcss error undefined
          $.plugin.loadedcss.push(value);
        });
    },

    end: function(){
        //console.log(this.loadedcss);
    }
};
```

Comment: JSON is a _notation_, not a data type.

Comment: @Alnitak - Yes it is not a data type.

Comment: @user397916 - With your edited code also you still cannot use this because it will point to current value params["js"] collection or map. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli my point was that there's no such thing as a 'json object' in Javascript.  What he has here is an _object literal_, which happens to _look like_ JSON.

Comment: @Alnitak - I totally agree with you :)

Comment: @shankarSangoli so fix that part of your answer... ;-)